# Azure Websites, Medium instance, 2 cores, how many application pools?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have just upgraded my test instance from a small "Standard"(1 core, 1.75gb RAM) instance to medium "Standard" instance (2 cores, 3.5gb RAM), due to potential performance issues, and this seemed a quick hit. We do have issues with application pools recycling and having to rewarm certain code modules. So with a medium instance I am concerned that I might have made our application pool issue worse, by having more than one pool to deal with?

So how many application pools would exist on my Medium Website instance, one or more?

Many thanks in advance.

P.S the other performance issues I believe are linked to the use of In-Proc Session configuration which works

```
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30">
       <providers>
          <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
       </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

I realise this is periphery to the question, but it might help provide some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 1 application pool per site no matter what size the VM is. an application pool is basically IIS terminology for how the process management (e.g: identity, quotas, number of processes, etc) for your site is carried on. It's really an implementation detail that you shouldn't necessarily worry about.

For your cold start issues, have you considered enabling the `Always On` setting for your site?

You can also add an entry for Application Initialization to warm any code paths you want to. This is how that would look like in your `web.config`

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" >
   <add initializationPage="/" />
   <add initializationPage="/Page2" />
   <add initializationPage="/Page3" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

And consider using [staged publishing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) to get around cold starts when you re-publish your site

Comment: Really interesting post, thanks, @ahmelsayed. Much clearer. Also thank you for the init code, I did not know about this, and at present we use pingdom for run a series of startup routines. This works even when the server might go cold due to being idle. Would you "doAppInitAfterRestart" deal with pool refreshes due to site being idle ? I have tried "Always on", but found it conflicted with Pingdom ie too many sites autopinging. We also use staged publishing, and it is great. However it confuses NewRelic, and the required New Relic config change forces a refresh....aah...

Comment: Actually `doAppInitAfterRestart` has to do with restarting the AppDomain rather than the entier worker process. Say if you change something in `web.config`, that normally doesn't restart the w3wp.exe, it just restarts the app running inside the process, this will ensure to run appinit in these situations. It will always run if the process recycles for any reason, provided that the process itself was started, that's why I suggested coupling it with `Always On` which just makes sure the process is up.

Comment: I may need to look again at "Always On" as it may keep the website warm in a more pervasive way than an external autoping service which would targets a specific URL.